# Emberjs view not updating on new record creation?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have route which uses ember hash to load multiple models like

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default Route.extend({
    model(params) {
        return Ember.RSVP.hash({
            contest: this.store.query('contest',{match: params.matchId}),
            match: this.store.findRecord('match', params.matchId)
        })
    }
});
```

and i create a new instance of contest in controller using the following code

```
    newContest() {
         this.store
            .createRecord('contest', {
                name: this.get('contestName'),
                fee: this.get('contestFee'),
                winning: this.get('contestWinning'),
                capacity: this.get('contestCapacity'),
                match: this.get('model').match.get('id')
            })
            .save();
    }
```

The problem being that it is not reflected in template which i am rendering as follows

```
        {{#each model.contest as |contest| }}
        <tr>
            <td>{{contest.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
```

where am i going wrong with this ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you use `this.store.query`. This method just makes a query via adapter, without any sort of caching.

Easiest way to update a model is by calling [`refresh`](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.1/classes/Route/methods/refresh?anchor=refresh) method of route. To do it from controller you can define `refresh` action in your route, then from controller do `this.send('refresh');` after saving new contest.